# Labeling by period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label

my dataset

```
name day value
A    7   88
A    15  101
A    21  121
A    29  56
B    21  131
B    30  78
B    35  102
C    8   80
C    16  101
...
```

I am trying to plot with values for these days, but I want to label because there are too many unique numbers of days.

I try to label it consistently,

Is there a way to speed up labeling by cutting it every 7 days(week)?

For example, ~ 7day = 1week,  8 ~ 14day = 2week, and so on.

**output what I want**

```
name day value week
A    7   88    1
A    15  101   3
A    21  121   3
A    29  56    5
B    21  131   3
B    30  78    5
B    35  102   5
C    8   80    2
C    16  101   3
```

thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract `1`, then use integer division by `7` and last add `1`:

```
df['week'] = (df['day'] - 1) // 7 + 1
print (df)
  name  day  value  week
0    A    7     88     1
1    A   15    101     3
2    A   21    121     3
3    A   29     56     5
4    B   21    131     3
5    B   30     78     5
6    B   35    102     5
7    C    8     80     2
8    C   16    101     3
```

Comment: hi! There are also days where the day is 0. In this case, I want to include 1 week. How do I solve it?

Comment: @ybin - You can replace `0` values to `1`, e.g. by `df['week'] = ((df['day'] - 1) // 7 + 1).clip(lower=1)` - it means lowest value is `1` or `df['week'] = ((df['day'] - 1) // 7 + 1).replace(0,1)`